# Snow Leopard connecting to Unbuntu 10.04 through Samba failure -- need help fixing

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, samba, mac-osx

I have a Ubuntu 10.04 web server. I want to connect to it with my OSX 10.6 machine and Finder.

I have installed openSSH and Samba on the Ubuntu machine.

In my `smb.conf` I have a Share Definition:

```
[www]
   comment = Development Computer WWW
   path = /var/www
   writeable = yes
   browseable = yes
   allow hosts = 192.168.1.
```

I can connect to the machine through Finder using a non-root user. When I attempt to add files thought Finder I get an "Insufficient Permissions" error.

Please help. I am not sure if the issue is in the Samba configuration or OSX 10.6

Thank you

EDIT (More Information): I am logging into the Ubuntu machine with a username and password. Currently the var/www is owned by root. I am logging into the Ubuntu machine with a non-root user.

Comment: Are you connecting as "Guest" or using a user/password on the Mac side?  If the later, does that user have write permissions to /var/www?

Comment: @Jeff Leyser username/password   --   no, currently var/www is owned by root and I am logging in with a non-root user. Should I configure SSH to allow a root login?

Comment: The problem is Samba, not SSH.  They use very different auth mechanisms, so how you login via SSH doesn't really matter.  When you are in Finder, how are you connecting to the 'www' share?

Comment: I can create a new folder on the SMB Share through Finder, but I cannot drag and drop a file from my OSX Desktop into the Share

Comment: What steps are you following to connect in Finder?  This matters, a lot! :)

Comment: Command K then smb://username@IP

Comment: Do I connect to the share, add a new folder. BUT I cannot drag a folder from the OSX Desktop and drop it into the share. Could this be a OSX 10.6 issue?

Comment: No, I use 10.6 & Samba no problem.  You have a permission problem.  Try the suggestions below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Samba uses its own authentication model.  You need to do one of the following:

1. Include `guest ok = yes` when defining the share in the smb.conf file, and then click use "Connect as Guest" when connecting from finder
2. Use `smbpasswd -a` on the Ubuntu system to create a Samba user, and use "Connect as Registered User" from Finder.

In either case, you'll need to change the ownership and/or permission of the directories you want to manipulate under /var/www to allow either "guest" or the user you create to write to them.